# sed to search and replace string from another file

Tags: awk, sed

I need some suggestion to make the below bash script using sed/awk in a one-liner way or if i can use python instead would be great for doing this search and replace task.

Here I created the search pattern in a file named "input.txt" with first column to search and second column for replace. Then I assign each column value on an array and calling in a for loop using sed utility to search and replace on "file.csv". This change only happens on the 3rd column only.

file.csv

```
Symbol,Name,Value
*,yy03LN-1,LM-GA-G01
*,yy5310-4,YP-QL-A03
*,yy5310-5,YP-QL-A10
```

input.txt

```
LM-GA-G01,LM-GA-G1
YP-QL-A03,YP-QL-A3
YP-QL-A10,YP-QL-A10
```

Expected results, to remove the 3rd column '0' number

file.csv

```
Symbol,Name,Value
*,yy03LN-1,LM-GA-G1
*,yy5310-4,YP-QL-A3
*,yy5310-5,YP-QL-A10
```

I created a shell script based on this condition, and this works better, but i need help similiar a single liner or short script to achieve this task.

```
#!/bin/bash
post=$(cat file.csv|awk -F "," '{print $NF}'| grep -v Index)
postar=($post)

for (( i=0; i<${#postar[@]}; ++i )); do
grep "${postar[$i]}" input.txt >> filtered.txt
done

left=$(cat filtered.txt|awk -F "," '{print $1}')
leftar=($left)
right=$(cat filtered.txt|awk -F "," '{print $2}')
rightar=($right)


for (( i=0; i<${#leftar[@]}; ++i )); do
sed -i -e 's/'"${leftar[$i]}"'/'"${rightar[$i]}"'/g' file.csv
done
```

Please note:- the line count of `input.txt` and `file.csv` are not same.

Please suggest

Thanks
Jay

Comment: Is there any point to the `input.txt` file? It seems you just want to remove the zero-padding from integers...

Comment: ```input.txt``` is not mandatory, i just placed to get the search/replace pattern. Not from every integers only string contains ```A01```,``` B03```,```C02``` and not no action for ```A10``` , ```B20```.

Comment: If your current example doesn't adequately cover your requirements then fix the example, don't try to describe some different input/output in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if there is more than removing `0`, you can dynamically generate `sed` program.

```
 awk -F, '{printf "s/%s/%s/\n",$1,$2}' input.txt
```

where

- `-F,` tell awk to use `,` as separator,
- `printf "s/%s/%s/\n",$1,$2` will generate substitution

this give with your input

```
s/LM-GA-G01/LM-GA-G1/
s/YP-QL-A03/YP-QL-A3/
s/YP-QL-A10/YP-QL-A10/
```

now feed it to sed

```
  awk -F, '{printf "s/%s/%s/\n",$1,$2}' input.txt | sed -i -f - file.csv
```

where

- `-i` use in place edition
- `-f -` use sed instructions from stdin (the awk generated part)

Comment: One of the few instances in which cross-language meta-programming isn't evil. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer this got worked for my use case. And this feeding method is awesome i will use this for my other use-cases

Comment: @DavidFoerster evil may be too far but there's no point using awk to generate a sed script to do a replacement when awk could easily just do the replacement itself instead.

Comment: @user183980 regarding `i will use this for my other use-cases` - don't do that, I'm not sure if I'd go quite as far as to call this approach an anti-pattern, but it's convoluted and fragile at best compared to simply doing the whole replacement in 1 call to awk. You don't need sed when you're using awk.

Comment: As some examples of fragility (there's probably others) - if your strings contained regexp metachars like `.` or `*` or backreferences like `&` or `\1` or separators like `/` or the values in $3 could be a substring of other values anywhere in the line or the values in $3 could also appear in $2 then this approach would fail while the awk script in [@Marius_Couet's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/729321/133219) would continue to work perfectly.

Comment: as Note by @EdMorton this method is perfomed by professional stunt, don't do this at home.

Answer (score 6):

The following uses the CSV-aware tool [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to remove the zero-padding of all numbers embedded in the value of the `Value` field:

```bash
$ mlr --csv put '$Value = gsub($Value, "([A-Z])0+([1-9])", "\1\2")' file
Symbol,Name,Value
*,yy03LN-1,LM-GA-G1
*,yy5310-4,YP-QL-A3
*,yy5310-5,YP-QL-A10
```

The `Value` field is modified using the `gsub()` function by matching any occurrence of the digit `0` (possibly repeated) following an upper-case letter (`[A-Z]`), followed by a digit that is not zero (`[1-9]`).  Any such match is replaced by the upper case letter and the non-zero digit, removing the string of zeros that is padding the integer.

The modification can be performed in-place using `mlr` with its `-I` option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I never knew about this tool ```mlr``` . Let me explore this more

Answer (score 5):

If your files aren't too large you can use `awk` :

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}
     {print $1,$2,($3 in a ? a[$3] : $3)}' input.txt file.csv
```

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` Set fields separators to `,`
- `NR==FNR` if the number record is equal to the file number record (if you are in the first file)
- `a[$1]=$2` Store into an array the second field using the first field as the key
- `$3 in a ? a[$3] : $3` if `$3` is a key in `a` print `a[$3]` else print `$3`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. one concern here if there is no keyword match found, this produces a whitespace. Simply change on file.csv from ```YP-QL-A03``` to ```YP-QL-A3```. Because my file.csv consist of more than 500 lines and only few of the lines triggers the match which i specify only on the ```input.txt``` file. And the line count of ```file.csv``` and ```input.txt``` are not same.

Comment: @user183980 changed it to work without having a key in the array

Comment: I'm getting an error ```  awk: cmd. line:3: {print $1,$2,($3 in a ? a[$3] : $3} ^ syntax error```

Comment: @user183980 I fixed the answer by changing `$3}` to `$3)}`.

Answer (score 3):

If this isn't all you need:

```
$ sed 's/0*\([0-9]*$\)/\1/' file.csv
Symbol,Name,Value
*,yy03LN-1,LM-GA-G1
*,yy5310-4,YP-QL-A3
*,yy5310-5,YP-QL-A10
```

then edit your question to provide a more truly representative example that includes cases where that doesn't work.

Comment: Great this is what I'm looking. This is looking only the 3rd column and removing the ```0``` charactor. but keeping ```0``` greater than ```10```. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Could you help explain this part ```0*\([0-9]*$\)/\1/'``` in sed, that would be great for me to understand

Comment: Match any number of 0s followed by any number of any digits. Capture the latter and reference it later by `\1`, thereby removing any preceding 0s.

Comment: Thanks, but how this search limited to 3rd column, because there are  ```0's``` in second column as well. And we never specify sed to look only in specific column right? please advise

Comment: The `$` anchors the regexp to the end of the line which means it can only match in the 3rd (last) column because the regexp is entirely digits, it'd need to include a `,` to be able to match any part of an earlier column.